# Adventure Works 2012

Tags: sql-server

I downloaed adventures work 2012 on my server and when I try to open the file, it is (tried to be) opened by VLC media player. So I can't attach it to my SSMS. I tried to uninstall VLC media Player but it is not working. What should I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes simply no sanes "it goes moves to VLC"????

Comment: @TomTom See my answer. I suspect they're trying to double click a database download and are seeing weirdness based on file associations, but without knowing exactly what kind of file it is, its hard to give specific advice.

Comment: Sory move is a miss typing of the words goes

Comment: What is the full name of the (unzipped) file?

Comment: You don't attach databases to SSMS, where is the sql instance you are trying to attach it to?  Local, or on a remote server.  You will need to either attach, import, or restore the database to the sql server instance you are trying to use.  Is there 1 file, or more then 1, what is/are the file extensions?

Comment: I don't understand what u meant by the full name of the zip file?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of file did you download exactly? A zip? A BAK? An MDF and LDF?

I can't imagine that double-clicking a database file would give you the results you want, so don't do that.

Instead, open your SQL Server Management Studio and import/attach/restore (again, depending on exactly what kind of file it is).

Comment: I did with Zip.its didn't work out

Comment: @Clement You'll need to unzip the download, either by right-clicking and "extract", or by using a utility like PKZip or something else. Where did you get the file exactly? [From this site](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks)?

Comment: Yes I got it from that site

Comment: @Clement The ZIP files I see on that site are all script packages. The database itself is BAK, which you'll need to restore using SSMS.

Comment: When I downloaded back it moved to VLC media player.that is the issue Bradc

Comment: @Clement That still makes no sense, what do you mean "it moved to VLC media player"?? Don't double-click or try to open it. Don't pay any attention to what kind of icon it gives it after download (which might be based on an errant file association). Just use SSMS to perform a restore.

Comment: Let me tried again.

Comment: Bradc, I just did the download but I still have same issue.

Comment: @Clement I don't think this is a database issue, I think you're just having trouble with file downloads and OS-level file associations. Maybe try at the user QA site https://superuser.com/

Comment: Is there a way I can share my screen with u so u can help me?

Comment: @Clement Do you have a company help desk? Are you doing this on y our own home PC?

Comment: I'm doing on my on PC

Comment: I know is not a databases questions but  a DBA Sql Jr level

Answer (score 0):

Look for Start+DefaultPrograms. There may be a rare dependency on database files with VLC or some other program.